# How to solve Uncaught (in promise) TypeError in react authentication?

Tags: reactjs, jwt, mern

I am pretty new to MERN stack. I am trying to setup user authentication using jwt. 
The problem is only occurring when I am using the front end to login. When I using POST man to make an http request, login successful is succesfull
However when I login using email and password I get the following error:

console

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
at authActions.js:40
```

I know it is showing where the error is but I am still unable to fix it.

authActions.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import setAuthToken from "../utils/setAuthToken";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING } from "./types";

// Register User
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/register", userData)
    .then(res => history.push("/login")) // re-direct to login on successful register
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};

// Login - get user token
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/login", userData)
    .then(res => {
      // Save to localStorage

      // Set token to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      // Set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};

// Set logged in user
export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded
  };
};

// User loading
export const setUserLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: USER_LOADING
  };
};

// Log user out
export const logoutUser = () => dispatch => {
  // Remove token from local storage
  localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
  // Remove auth header for future requests
  setAuthToken(false);
  // Set current user to empty object {} which will set isAuthenticated to false
  dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
};
```

Following is my code for login front end.

login.jsx

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // If logged in and user navigates to Login page, should redirect them to dashboard
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }
  validateForm() {
    return this.state.email.length > 0 && this.state.password.length > 0;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard"); // push user to dashboard when they login
    }

    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submit called");
    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    this.props.loginUser(userData);
  };

  render() {
    const errors = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="Login">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormGroup controlId="email" bs="large">
            <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
            <span className="red-text">{errors.emailnotfound}</span>
            <FormControl
              autoFocus
              type="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              className={classnames("", {
                invalid: errors.email || errors.emailnotfound
              })}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup controlId="password" bs="large">
            <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
            <span className="red-text">
              {errors.password}
              {errors.passwordincorrect}
            </span>
            <FormControl
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              type="password"
              className={classnames("", {
                invalid: errors.password || errors.passwordincorrect
              })}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button
            block
            bs="large"
            disabled={!this.validateForm()}
            type="submit"
          >
            Login
          </Button>
          <br />
          <p> Dont have account ? </p>
          <Link to="/register">
            {" "}
            <p style={{ color: "blue" }}> Join Us </p>{" "}
          </Link>
        </form>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have left out some import statements to shorten the code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on line 40, wich is in `payload: err.response.data`.

If it says

> Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

It means that `err.response` is `ndefined`.

You should do some checking before passing that. Maybe it's returning a different error that doesn't have `.response`.

Try `console.log(err)` to check what is inside of it.

Comment: Tried console logging the err.. it says `Error InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code from

`onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}` to `onSubmit={()=>this.handleSubmit()}`

And

`onChange={this.handleChange}`to `onChange={()=>this.handleChange()}`

because of this your password and email are not getting set to state and your API `axios.post("/api/users/login", userData)` is throwing exception.

Comment: Does not work.. If I change the function calling method, the text area remains unchanged when I type.

Comment: @arjun-kashyap I  have updated the code kindly check

Comment: I dont think that is the problem. I console.logged the userData, and it is set to the values

Comment: It seems your server is getting error . Does your server supports cors request?

Comment: It does.. I have added cors.. When I am testing this using Postman, it is successful

Comment: You need to update your axios to add cors setting in request. This is the [axios cors setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56730369/how-to-send-request-to-an-api-on-remote-server-via-webpack-devlopment-server-usi/56730910?noredirect=1#comment100021612_56730910)

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you don't stringify the data before you send it. Require the `qs` library and change your code to that:

```
axios
.post("/api/users/register", qs.stringify( userData ))
.then(res => history.push("/login")) // re-direct to login on successful register
.catch(err =>
  dispatch({
    type: GET_ERRORS,
    payload: err.response.data
  })
);
```

You can also check that the data is not sent correctly by looking the `Network` tab in your Browser's Dev Tools. I expect to send the data in a wrong format. I hope that I am correct.

Comment: Not working.. I used JSON.stringify(). I am getting `Error Error: Request failed with status code 400`